# What does '\' mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am currently learning about 'dereferencing' in Perl and need your help in understanding what the '\' means in the line below..

```
$ra = \$a;
```

Comment: If you are currently learning about it, what do your books and manuals say?

Comment: my lecture notes didnt elaborate what it meant, leading me to search on google. didnt find a satis ans, so i asked it here.

Comment: @Roy: make sure you pick a correct answer. ☹

Comment: Searching for Perl information using Google is not a great idea. There are a lot of sites out there giving dodgy Perl advice. When you have a Perl question, I recommend searching the Perl documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/. As tchrist demonstrates below, you have accepted an inaccurate answer.

Comment: @Roy: you should ask your lecturer why you have never been shown where to find the [official Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org), which contains all the reference information you need. You don't need to go to google for something like this; the answers you find there will be unreliable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators).

> Unary "\" creates a reference to
>   whatever follows it. See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
>   and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). Do not confuse this
>   behavior with the behavior of
>   backslash within a string, although
>   both forms do convey the notion of
>   protecting the next thing from
>   interpolation.

Comment: Actually, or creates several references to the several things following in list context, *e.g.* `@r = \\(@a, %b, &c)` and `@r = \localtime`.

Comment: when is there backslash "\" in regex or in string it is called ESCAPE, otherwise it is called REFERENCE

Answer (score 28):

*As I have elsewhere previously written…*

Unary `\` creates a reference to whatever follows it.  Used on a list, it creates a list of references.

Do not confuse this behavior with the behavior of backslash within a string, although both forms do convey the vaguely negational notion of protecting the next thing from interpretation.  This resemblance is not entirely accidental.

You can create a reference to any named variable or subroutine with a backslash.  You may also use it on an anonymous scalar value like `7` or `"camel"`, although you won’t often need to.  This operator works like the `&` (address-of) operator in C or C⁺⁺— at least at first glance.

Here are some examples:

```
$scalarref = \$foo;
$constref  = \186_282.42;
$arrayref  = \@ARGV;
$hashref   = \%ENV;
$coderef   = \&handler;
$globref   = \*STDOUT;
```

The backslash operator can do more than produce a single reference.  It will generate a whole list of references if applied to a list.

As mentioned earlier, the backslash operator is usually used on a single referent to generate a single reference, but it doesn’t have to be. When used on a list of referents, it produces a list of corresponding references.  The second line of the following example does the same thing as the first line, since the backslash is automatically distributed throughout the whole list.

```
@reflist = (\$s, \@a, \%h, \&f);     # List of four references
@reflist = \($s,  @a   %h,  &f);     # Same thing
```

If a parenthesized list contains exactly one array or hash, then all of its values are interpolated and references to each returned:

```
@reflist = \(@x);                    # Interpolate array, then get refs
@reflist = map { \$_ } @x;           # Same thing
```

This also occurs when there are internal parentheses:

```
@reflist = \(@x, (@y));              # But only single aggregates expand
@reflist = (\@x, map { \$_ } @y);    # Same thing
```

If you try this with a hash, the result will contain references to the values (as you’d expect), but references to *copies* of the keys (as you might *not* expect).

Because array and hash slices are really just lists, you can backslash a slice of either of these to get a list of references.   Each of the next four lines does exactly the same thing:

```
@envrefs = \@ENV{"HOME", "TERM"};         # Backslashing a slice
@envrefs = \@ENV{ qw<HOME TERM> };        # Backslashing a slice
@envrefs = \( $ENV{HOME},  $ENV{TERM} );  # Backslashing a list
@envrefs = ( \$ENV{HOME}, \$ENV{TERM} );  # A list of two references
```

Since functions can return lists, you can apply a backslash to them.  If you have more than one function to call, first interpolate each function’s return values into a larger list and then backslash the whole thing:

```
@reflist = \fx();
@reflist = map { \$_ } fx();                # Same thing

@reflist = \( fx(), fy(), fz() );
@reflist = ( \fx(), \fy(), \fz() );         # Same thing
@reflist = map { \$_ } fx(), fy(), fz();    # Same thing
```

The backslash operator always supplies a list context to its operand, so those functions are all called in list context.  If the backslash is itself in scalar context, you’ll end up with a reference to the last value of the list returned by the function:

```
@reflist = \localtime();      # Ref to each of nine time elements
$lastref = \localtime();      # Ref to whether it’s daylight savings time
```

In this regard, the backslash behaves like the named Perl list
operators, such as `print`, `reverse`, and `sort`, which always
supply a list context on their right no matter what might be happening on their left.  As with named list operators, use an explicit `scalar`to force what follows into scalar context:

```
$dateref = \scalar localtime();    # \"Sat Nov 13 10:41:30 2010"
```

*And now you know… the **rest** of the story.*

(with apologies to the late Paul Harvey)

Comment: I just used a reference to DATA with \\*DATA to use the Template::Toolkit with LaTeX. I put the LaTeX section in the DATA section and then used the reference to that as the template in `process`: Perl is so cool.

Comment: Also thanks for showing that \\( ... ) distributes, creating a ref to each element. I would have guessed that would make a ref to the array of that list, but now that makes sense, otherwise what would we need [ ... ] for. Thanks

Comment: that's really comprehensive, that's tchrist.

Comment: @Joel, the last time *I* made a reference to `DATA`, which was yesterday, I passed `"<&DATA"` in on the command line to be deftly handled by “magic open” in the normal `<>` filter processing that the script did. Not that is a reference *per se*. ☺

Comment: wow, I'm going to have to think about that one for a bit! I was just saying that I am learning "Level 2" Perl and its cool to see that you can do all these crazy gynmastics with it.

Answer (score 4):

The Perl documentation is great and thorough, use it early and often. May I recommend `perldoc perlreftut`, the perl references tutorial, or `perldoc perlref` for more. Afterwards `perldoc perlintro` and `perldoc perltoc` or `perldoc perl` to see where to go from there.

And yes it creates a reference to the variable $a and stores it in the variable $ra.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a reference to the variable on the right hand side; kind of like a pointer in C (without the pointer arithmetic) or a pointer in Java.

See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for a lot more information on the subject.

Dereferentiation is done via `$$a` for scalars, `@$a` for arrays, etc.

Comment: @tchrist This answer is not wrong.  It does not completely tell you what \ does, but the question wasn't "what does the \ operator do in all cases", it was "what the '\' means in the line below".  The line below was `$ra = \$a;`, and in that line it does create a reference to the variable on the righthand side.  The answer also points a reference document that explains the operator fully.

Comment: @Chas. Owens: it is an incomplete answer to the title of this question.

Comment: Ach well, I guess on the line `$ra = \$a;` a reference to the variable on the right hand side is not created then ;P