# what does backslash '\' mean in perl language?

Tags: perl, backslash

[image]

in the above picture, there are \ before perl variables, what does the backslash mean?

Comment: Add code as text not as immage

Comment: Code is text. Why do some many people think it's useful to post images of code?

Comment: Please, do some research before asking questions. If you had, you would have found this similar question: [What does '\' mean in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4173496/4990392). (your question should be closed as dupe of this one in my opinion - I can't vote to close though)

Comment: Yes, I know, but how to close this question?

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you can save a reference to another variable in a scalar variable:

```
my $string = "Test";
my $str_ref = \$string;

my @list = (1, 2, 3);
my $lst_ref = \@list;

my %hash = ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
my $hsh_ref = \%hash;
```

To read or modify the referenced variable you have to dereference it. For that you use the funny character of the original variable type:

```
$$str_ref = "Something else";
print $string; # -> Something else
print $$str_ref; # -> The same

@$lst_ref = (4, 5, 6);
print join(' ', @list); # -> 4 5 6
print join(' ', @$lst_ref); # The same

%$hsh_ref = ('c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
print join(' ', sort values %hash); # -> 3 4
print join(' ', sort values %$hsh_ref); # The same
```

The referenced values of list and hash references can be accessed with the `->` operator:

```
print $lst_ref->[0]; # -> 4

print $hsh_ref->{'c'}; # -> 3
```

The longer syntax for dereferencing is using `{}`: `${$str_ref}`, `@{$lst_ref}` and `%{$hsh_ref}`.

Answer (score 0):

backslash in this case means the reference of the variable.

Read [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more informations

Comment: @ downvoter thanks dir downvoting without explanation