# Why does a scalar variable that contains a code snippet not getting stored in a CSV file properly?

Tags: perl

I have a variable `$code = \'print "Hello World";'`.

When I try to write this value in a CSV file using perl, I see something like `SCALAR(0x6ac7890)` under the CODE column in the CSV. I was expecting `print "Hello World";` under the column. Can someone please clarify what has went wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does '\' mean in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173496/what-does-mean-in-perl)

Comment: Why do you use `$var=\'string'` instead of `$var='string'` ? The first one assigns a reference to the string, the second the string itself.

Comment: CSV is a complete red herring here. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable doesn't contain a code snippet. It contains a *reference* to a code snippet. That's not the same thing.

To get what you want, you can either store an **actual** code snippet:

```
$code = 'print "Hello world"';
print $code;
```

Or you can continue to store a reference, but de-reference it as you print it:

```
$code = \'print "Hello world"';
print $$code;  # Note $$ to de-reference variable
```